# NFC intent filter for http:// data

Tags: android, nfc

I have made an app which plays a video from the link saved on an NFC tag. The links to these videos will end like .3gp or .mp4 etc like this http://commonsware.com/misc/test2.3gp.

My manifest is like this

```
<activity
            android:name="com.example.nfcv1.VedioView"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED"/>
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
                <data android:scheme="http" 
                        android:pathPrefix="/.3gp"/>
            </intent-filter>
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIDEOVIEW" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

but the problem is this activity starts on any kind of link e.g www.google.com
I want to restrict this activity to only to open when links to video is detected, otherwise go to the browser to open the link.

Answer (score 1):

You should check the notation of the file extension. I guess you rather want to write **"android:pathPrefix=*.3pg"**.

In addition the documentation requests a host element. So you might try to add something like **android:host="*"** in your data element.

The documentation says:

> *android:pathPattern*
>
> The path part of a URI. The path attribute specifies a complete path that is matched against the complete path in an Intent object. The pathPrefix attribute specifies a partial path that is matched against only the initial part of the path in the Intent object. The pathPattern attribute specifies a complete path that is matched against the complete path in the Intent object, but it can contain the following wildcards:
>
> **An asterisk ('*') matches a sequence of 0 to many occurrences of the immediately preceding character.** A period followed by an asterisk (".*") matches any sequence of 0 to many characters.
>
> Because '\' is used as an escape character when the string is read from XML (before it is parsed as a pattern), you will need to double-escape: For example, a literal '*' would be written as "\\*" and a literal '\' would be written as "\\\\". This is basically the same as what you would need to write if constructing the string in Java code.
>
> For more information on these three types of patterns, see the descriptions of PATTERN_LITERAL, PATTERN_PREFIX, and PATTERN_SIMPLE_GLOB in the PatternMatcher class.
>
> **These attributes are meaningful only if the scheme and host attributes are also specified for the filter.**

See: [Android documentation for the data element](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/data-element.html)

Comment: Its not working... now it directs to the browser for both type of links... i want it to direct to browser for normal links but direct to my app when it a video links ending on .3gp or .mp4